# Do the "All Units" orders get applied to additional recruits?

Tags: valkyria-chronicles

In Valkyria Chronicles, do "All Units *x*" orders affect only the characters currently on the map, or will they affect reinforcements as well?

Answer (score 4):

Reinforcements appear at the start of the round, before orders can be given. As orders are only active for one round, orders can never have an effect on untis in reserve.